# AndroidRuntime: General error during class generation: can't load this type of class file

Tags: java, android, groovy

I tried to run the following code in Android:

```
final GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();

final StringBuilder groovyScript = new StringBuilder();
groovyScript.append("class Sample {");
groovyScript.append("String sayIt(){\"Groovy says: Cool!\"}");
groovyScript.append("}");

Class groovy = classLoader.parseClass(groovyScript.toString());
GroovyObject groovyObj = null;
try {
      groovyObj = (GroovyObject) groovy.newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(MainApplication.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(MainApplication.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
String output = (String) groovyObj.invokeMethod("sayIt", null);
```

But unfortunately it throws an error:

```
01-06 11:28:01.109 19597-19597/com.mscharhag.groovytodo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 11:28:01.109 19597-19597/com.mscharhag.groovytodo E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mscharhag.groovytodo, PID: 19597
01-06 11:28:01.109 19597-19597/com.mscharhag.groovytodo E/AndroidRuntime: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
01-06 11:28:01.109 19597-19597/com.mscharhag.groovytodo E/AndroidRuntime: General error during class generation: can't load this type of class file
```

I was trying to run **Groovy** in Android and Im almost there! By the way I followed this tutorial: [Creating Android Apps with Groovy 2.4](http://www.mscharhag.com/groovy/creating-android-apps-with-groovy)

Comment: Did you find a solution?